# How to get Room Available between checkin datetime and checkout datetime

Tags: datetime, search, cakephp, between

I have 3 tables in my database. First table is rooms , second table is booking_details and third is reserved_rooms. i user cakephp4.2, mysql.

rooms Table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/C5efV.png)

booking_details Table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Vzmb5.png)

reserved_rooms Table
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/D3fl9.png)

cakephp query search form fields checkin, checkout & room_type

lets say
checkin = 2023-07-12 20:00:00, checkout = 2023-07-14 20:00:00, room_type = 1

how to get all room available between above search parameter and my checkout time is 24 hr.

Comment: try where: `checkin >= 2023-07-12 20:00:00 AND checkout <= 2023-07-14 20:00:00`